# When garbage collector decides to clean inpustream object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, download, garbage

**Current short question for REST API app.**

Let's suppose we have Map<String, List> files4users in @Component class.

This map contains name of user and connected csv file that the user can download.
So an user can download the file anytime.

But what if an user already downloaded the file and we want to exclude this file for usage to clean memory.

- Is there some option how we can handle this? For example when user call REST API download/data --> we return ResponseEntity with this kind of file.
- How can we quarantee that garbage collector will clean this inputstream? Let's imagine that the file is 500MB.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to exclude it, remove it from the `files4users` data structure.

Comment: Not sure what `InputStream` you are referring to.  But if you have 500MB files you probably shouldn't cache them in memory.  And if they are in the file system, then it is not up to the Java GC to delete them.